# Exception when trying to implement AWS SDK

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, aws-sdk

I'm running into an error when trying to implement the AWS SDK into our Java Web Application. I'm trying to write a simple method to save an image to an S3 Bucket and the error happens when I trigger that method.

**Stack Trace**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoKeepalive(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:95)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:198)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:129)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:434)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:416)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:400)
    at com.artistbomb.common.CommonUtility.saveImage(CommonUtility.java:254)
```

Based on what I've seen from Google, I have a feeling that this issue is related to an error with my Build Path configuration. I've included all of the AWS jars as well as all of the third party jars and I've gone through and removed older versions of the libraries.

**Classpath**

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-acl-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/anet-java-sdk-1.4.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-all-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.3.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/httpmime-4.3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-all-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.5.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.5.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail-api-1.4.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/quartz-1.8.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/restfb-1.6.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/scribe-1.3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.0.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.0.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.0.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-mock-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xerces-2.6.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.8.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.18.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ecwid-mailchimp.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/guava-17.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/java-lutung-mandrill.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.5.1-javadoc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.5.1-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.10.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that there were a couple old library versions inside of my project's /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory which were causing dependency issues. It's important that you remove duplicate, older libraries from the Build Path **as well as** the lib directory.

Comment: For me it was old versions of org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient & httpcore getting pulled in by a transitive maven dependency.  I excluded those dependencies and things started working.

Comment: @pedorro Can you please share the pom.xml you were using. I was downloading the jar and using that, and still facing the issue even after removing the duplicate dependencies. Will go the Maven way now

Comment: @MitakshGupta I just added exclusions in my pom to the dependency that was pulling in old versions.  The excluded dependencies are apache httpcomponents - httpcore & httpclient.  I can't really post a whole pom in the comments.

Comment: @Dan it worked for me. I deleted the older version of httpclient and httpcore jar.